# what is s meant by s box row and column in DES?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

> [image]

What is this? And tell me about what are rows when selected 1st and last bit???

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking… and if I do, the question might be a bit too broad. So, to clarify — can you please explain what exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

S-box stand for substitution box. For every possible 6 bit input we replace with 4 bit output.
For visual convenience the input is broken up into 4 bits and 2 bits. Giving a 4*16 matrix in each cell we have the 4 bit output for the input designated by that row and column.
The 4 bits are the original bits and the 2 bits are from the expansion copied from neighboring 4 bit blocks.

We now know the DES cipher was designed to be resilient to differencial cryptanalysis which IBM and the NSA new of a whole 16 years before Eli Biham reinvented the technique and told the world.